# How to know whether my control be used in VisualBrush

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

We can use VisualBrush to capture any UIElement. And I want to know is any VisualBrush catch my UserControl.

The demo code as follows:

```xml
        <Border>
            <Border.Background>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl}"></VisualBrush>
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>
        <local:MyUserControl x:Name="MyUserControl"></local:MyUserControl>
```

How to write the code to know this control be capture by any VisualBrush?

```cs
    class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public bool IsInVisualBrush()
        {
            // How to check?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the CyclicBrushToChannelsMapField field to get which VisualBrush is attached to this Visual

```cs
    class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public bool IsInVisualBrush()
        {
            return GetVisualBrushes().Any();
        }

        private List<VisualBrush> GetVisualBrushes()
        {
            var type = typeof(Visual);
            var cyclicBrushToChannelsMapField = type.GetField("CyclicBrushToChannelsMapField", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var cyclicBrushToChannelsMap = cyclicBrushToChannelsMapField.GetValue(null);

            var getValueMethod = cyclicBrushToChannelsMap.GetType().GetMethod("GetValue");
            var cyclicBrushToChannelsMapDictionary = getValueMethod.Invoke(cyclicBrushToChannelsMap, new object[] { this });
            var dictionary = cyclicBrushToChannelsMapDictionary as IDictionary;

            var visualBrushes = dictionary.Keys.OfType<VisualBrush>().ToList();
            return visualBrushes;
        }
    }
```